# Read audio file from assets on Android

Tags: android, audio, assets

I am trying to play audio files stored in the assets directory, but before I even read a file I get the error "error occured java.io.FileNotFoundException: track.mp3". Here's how I read it:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("track.mp3");
```

I read a lot of descriptions on the internet, but no success.

Comment: You could also store it in the raw directory under res, that way you can load it easier into the media player, since you can provide a res id.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to play a large number of files, so I don't really want to track every single one of them in my resources.

Comment: For me it was case issue. File name was MP3 format in asset folder but I was using mp3 from code. By using exactly same name solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should work for you:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("track.mp3");

MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

Otherwise, check if the file is in the right folder and the name is "track.mp3".

Comment: Well, as I said, before I even use MediaPlayer object, I get the FileNotFoundException. It is thrown after I open AssetFileDescriptor.

Comment: This is the code path I'm using but it doesn't work:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124378/mp3-audio-in-the-android-assets-folder-fails-to-play-from-a-signed-and-zip-align

Answer (score 0):

Right-click your "track.mp3" file, with the "Refactor" > "Move" command, move your file to another directory (e.g. "res"). With  this same command, move it back to your "assets" directory. For me, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Android guidelines suggest for Audio use `res/raw` folder. So make sure that all audio are there and when you read you can use this method:

```
void playAudio(Context mContext, String sound){
    new AudioPlayer().play(mContext, mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(
            sound,"raw", mContext.getPackageName()));
}
```

And if you need something line audio player then take a look at [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            AssetFileDescriptor afd;
            try {
                afd = getAssets().openFd("1.mp3");
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                          Toast.makeText(LearnActivity.this, "Error Playing audio from Asset directory",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Otherwise, check if the file is in the right folder and the name is "track.mp3".

Comment: Code-only answers are low quality answers.