# Mp3 audio in the Android Assets folder fails to play from a signed and zip-aligned APK

Tags: android, audio, andengine, assets, motodev-studio

I am loading mp3 files to play in an Android game based on AndEngine. When I package my game as an APK, mp3 audio in the assets folder throws the error "can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed."

However, when I run the game using the run > button in Eclipse (MOTODEV Studio 3.0.2), the app is packaged, deployed to a device and the game has sound.  Works perfectly on a device.

If I package the app using "Export Android Application", which creates a signed APK ready to deploy in the Android Market and then install that APK on a device, the game functions perfectly **except** the sound doesn't play and throws the following error:

```
> 02-02 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925): AndEngine 02-02 20:42:31.433:
> E/AndEngine(1925): java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be
> opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed 02-02
> 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925):  at
> android.content.res.AssetManager.openAssetFd(Native Method) 02-02
> 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925):  at
> android.content.res.AssetManager.openFd(AssetManager.java:330) 02-02
> 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925):  at
> org.anddev.andengine.audio.music.MusicFactory.createMusicFromAsset(MusicFactory.java:75)
> 02-02 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925):    at
> com.snoffleware.android.roshambomb.PlayLevelActivity.onLoadResources(PlayLevelActivity.java:255)
> 02-02 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925):    at
> org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.doResume(BaseGameActivity.java:168)
> 02-02 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925):    at
> org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onWindowFocusChanged(BaseGameActivity.java:85)
> 02-02 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925):    at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onWindowFocusChanged(PhoneWindow.java:2012)
> 02-02 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925):    at
> android.view.View.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(View.java:3924) 02-02
> 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowFocusChanged(ViewGroup.java:659)
> 02-02 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925):    at
> android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1968) 02-02
> 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 02-02
> 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925):  at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 02-02 20:42:31.433:
> E/AndEngine(1925):    at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 02-02
> 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 02-02
> 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 02-02 20:42:31.433:
> E/AndEngine(1925):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:850)
> 02-02 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925):    at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608) 02-02
> 20:42:31.433: E/AndEngine(1925):  at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried deploying the APK to a Kindle Fire, Motorolo Droid and Motorolo Droid 2 Global.  The game works on all of these devices but without sound.

The audio is stored as mp3 files in a folder under Assets called Sound.  An example filename is "music-a-nebulas-promise.mp3".  I have tried renaming one of the files, "simple.mp3", worried that dashes are not allowed in the naming but it didn't make any difference.

The code that loads the audio is as follows and please note, when I run the application using MOTODEV Studio the sound is played back perfectly.  It is only when I try to export the app as an APK and install it that I get the aforementioned error regarding compression:

```
SoundFactory.setAssetBasePath("sound/");
        MusicFactory.setAssetBasePath("sound/");
        try {
            if (!level.getMusic().equals("")) {
                backgroundMusic = MusicFactory.createMusicFromAsset(this.mEngine.getMusicManager(), this,   level.getMusic());
                backgroundMusic.setLooping(true);

            } else {
                // music is turned on but there is no music file -- protect
                // against crash
                isMusic = false;
            }
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            Debug.e(e);
            // music is turned on but the music file was not found -- protect
            // against crash
            isMusic = false;
        }

        try {
            collisionSound = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), this, "sfx-collision.mp3");
            portalSound = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), this, "sfx-portal-activated.mp3");
            winningSound = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), this, "sfx-winning.mp3");
            losingSound = SoundFactory.createSoundFromAsset(this.mEngine.getSoundManager(), this, "sfx-losing.mp3");
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            Debug.e(e);
            isSound = false;
        }
```

The AndEngine method that initializes the audio:

```
public static Music createMusicFromAsset(final MusicManager pMusicManager, final Context pContext, final String pAssetPath) throws IOException {
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    final AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescritor = pContext.getAssets().openFd(MusicFactory.sAssetBasePath + pAssetPath);
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(assetFileDescritor.getFileDescriptor(), assetFileDescritor.getStartOffset(), assetFileDescritor.getLength());
    mediaPlayer.prepare();

    final Music music = new Music(pMusicManager, mediaPlayer);
    pMusicManager.add(music);

    return music;
}
```

I have tried converting the mp3 files to both ogg and wav.  Both ogg and wav throw the same error as mp3 files.

Since the game sound works when I run or debug it using Eclipse that seems to leave the final export step as the culprit.  I have seen posts that suggest controlling the build process to prevent compression of files in the Assets folder but I'm not sure how to accomplish that from MOTODEV Studio.

I have also seen posts that suggest storing the mp3 audio in the res/raw folder but since audio in the Assets folder plays when run from Eclipse, it seems that it should also work when packaged as an APK.

### Version details

I am current targeting Android SDK level 13 (Android 3.2) using Android SDK Tools v.15 and Android SDK Platform-tools v.9 -- so thinking it might have something to do with the SDK tools, I updated the SDK to v.16 and the platform tools to v.10 but that did not fix the problem.

Comment: you should check [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186866/java-io-filenotfoundexception-this-file-can-not-be-opened-as-a-file-descriptor) from a duplicate question

Comment: Thanks. I viewed that question already.  Quote: "You can trick aapt into not compressing the file by using a extention that is not compressed (e.g. mp3)."  As I stated, my files end in the .mp3 extension.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your app works when run from within Eclipse (or MOTODEV Studio) on debug is it is not going through the full path that occurs on export.  I don't have the SDK build process chart in front of me, but there is one out there.  I'm sure a bit of probing the Ant scripts will expose what is going on.

I say this because there's nothing MOTODEV Studio does different from Eclipse wrt the build process. While there is a separate "Export with MOTODEV Studio" menu item, all that's happening there is a couple of fields are being pre-populated with information as a convenience and access to your certificate store. Otherwise, the export process is the same as Eclipse+ADT (which is what it is).

Comment: I thought that I would mention that I was using MOTODEV Studio in the spirit of completeness but I see from your profile @Eric that you are an authoritative resource on how MOTODEV Studio functions so I'm taking your word on it.  :)

Comment: Yep. I catch any posts that mention MOTODEV. But I also want to see it work for you. This might be a case where using a different subject line might yield better answers. IMHO, it's wordy and may put some potential readers off.  It seems to me this is one of those topics that I would've expected to see an answer from @commonsware already.

Comment: That's a good point. I've changed the title. I'm not sure if it is for the better or worse but a lot of times figuring out the right question to ask is what gets you halfway to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be related to the mediaPlayer.prepare() method in the MusicFactory.java of AndEngine. I've just comment out line 91 (as in the following code snipet) and the MP3 resource was loaded without any exceptions. I think the same can be done with the asset loading method.

```
public static Music createMusicFromResource(final MusicManager pMusicManager, final Context pContext, final int pMusicResID) throws IOException {
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(pContext, pMusicResID);
        **//mediaPlayer.prepare();**

        final Music music = new Music(pMusicManager, mediaPlayer);
        pMusicManager.add(music);

        return music;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the audio-files in the "RAW" folder and play them via:

```
mPlayer2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.MUSICTAG);
mPlayer2.start();
```

This way, there should be no problems with compression.

Comment: Also, another good solution could be the following:
If you do not include the assets in your apk, you could download them to the SD card of the user after installing. From there are no size problems anymore. But you should warn the user and probably only allow downloading, if WiFi is activated.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't want to put the audio files in the RAW folder as there are different sets of audio in different builds which are hooked up via xml level definition files.  So, if the code has references to R.raw.Filename1 and I have actually copied in Filename2, I would get a compile time error. The thing that is killing me though is that the sound works when I run the game from Eclipse but it doesn't function when the release APK is created.  That leads me to believe that the code solution I chose works fine and that the packaging process is wrong (probably hubris on my part but shrug...)