# Can you play a mp3 file from the assets folder?

Tags: android

I store all my sounds in the res folder. I'm wondering if there is a way to store them in the assets folder and play them from there?

This is the code I'm using now:

```
void StartSound(int id) {
    if (id==0)
        return;

    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float actualVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float maxVolume = (float) audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    // float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
    float volume=(float) ( .01*(double)cGlobals.iVol);

    // Is the sound loaded already?
    if (nLastSound!=0)
        soundPool.stop(nLastSound); 

    int t=soundPool.play(id, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
    nLastSound=t;
}
```

I want to change this to avoid a memory error when the APK tries to load.  If I remove some of the files from the res folder it works fine. I'm hopping I want have the same issue if they are saved as a file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466888/read-audio-file-from-assets-on-android

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it in another way too. Put the .mp3 files under res/Raw folder and use the following code:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.android);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: can we use asset folder as well...?

Answer (score 9):

```
private void startSound(String filename){
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(filename);
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
    player.prepare();
    player.start();
}
```

Comment: openFd throws an IOException, so that would need to be handled.

Comment: Yup, but that's kind of trivial.

Comment: where is filename? Is it under assets / under raw?

Comment: afd needs to be closed after setDataSource is called

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following code to play a specific audio file (i.e `your_file.mp3`) in your **assets** folder with:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getAssets().openFd("your_file.mp3");
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
afd.close();
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

And to play a **raw** resource file (i.e `your_file`) with:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.your_file));                    
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
afd.close();
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: You initialized `MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();` but you rather called `player.prepare();`. etc.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

start sound

```
startSound("mp3/ba.mp3");
```

method

```
private void startSound(String filename) {
    AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
    try {
        afd = getResources().getAssets().openFd(filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        assert afd != null;
        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        player.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    player.start();
}
```